# Remove Specific td text when having duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having table data like this

[image]

how to remove text on specific td ( Generasi, Unit Code, Agent Code, Unit Name ) with having duplicate text and keep only 1

so the results can be like this

[image]

this is my fiddle
[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/n7mfz094/)

Comment: Loop through the `tr` elements, then loop through its `td` elements. If the text of the `td` is the same as the text from the corresponding cell in the previous row, replace it with an empty string.

Comment: this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n7mfz094/

Comment: That's the same link as in your question. There's no code in it that tries to remove duplicates, all it does is sort the table.

Comment: that's because i don't  know how to....

Comment: sort the table is my first step before to remove the duplicates...

Comment: What part of it don't you know how to do? jQuery has the `.each()` method to loop over a selection. And you can use `.find()` to find the elements within the current row.

Comment: The callback function of `.each()` gets the index of the element, you should be able to use that to access the corresponding `td` in the previous row.

Comment: This is what programming is all about. Taking all these pieces that you should know how to do, and figuring out how to put them together to solve your problem. It's a creative process, you can't expect to find solutions already written for you for everything.

Comment: This is all just a long-winded way of saying that you shouldn't come here looking for us to write the code for you. You're expected to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself. We'll help you fix it, but not write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Have  Fixed this. Please find the below changes in html and script.
**This code will add a table below your table which is not sorted and remove your js totally and paste the below.**
**In HTML I have added a div below**

```js
var FinalIndex = [];
var tbl = $('table#tableUnit tr').get().map(function(row) {
  return $(row).find('td').get().map(function(cell) {
    return $(cell).html();
  });
});
/* console.log(tbl) */
$.each(tbl, function(index, data) {
  if (data.length > 5) {
    console.log('data:' + index);
    count = 0;
    $.each(tbl, function(indexF, dataF) {
      if (indexF <= index) {
        if (data[0] == dataF[0] && data[1] == dataF[1] && data[2] == dataF[2] && data[3] == dataF[3] && count == 0 && count == 0) {
          count = count + 1;
          if (index == indexF) {
            console.log("comparing :" + index + "with" + indexF);
            console.log('count:' + count);
            console.log(data[0] + '.' + data[1] + "  first value  " + dataF[0]);
            FinalIndex.push(index);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    FinalIndex.push(index);
  }
});
console.log(FinalIndex)

function makeTable(tbl) {
  var table = '<table>';
  $.each(tbl, function(index, value) {

    if (jQuery.inArray(index, FinalIndex) !== -1) {
      table += '<tr>';
      $.each(value, function(ind, v1) {
        /* console.log(ind); */

        table += '<td>' + v1 + '</td>';

      });
      table += '</tr>';
    }

  });
  /* return ($(table)); */
  table += '</table>';
  console.log(table);
  $('.finalTable').html(table);
};

makeTable(tbl);

$('#btnOrig').click(function(){
  $('#orig_table').toggle();
});
```

```css
#orig_table{border:1px solid red;box-sizing:border-box;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnOrig">Show Original Table</button>
<div id="orig_table">
<table class="table" id="tableUnit" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 7em;"><strong>Generasi</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 20em;"><strong>Unit Code</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 20em;"><strong>Agent Code Unit</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 6em;"><strong>Unit Name</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 6em;" class="center"><strong>No.</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 5em;"><strong>Agent Code</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 15em;"><strong>Agent Name</strong></th>

      <th style="width: 15em;"><strong>VOC</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 15em;"><strong>KPM</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 15em;" class="right"><strong>Case</strong></th>
      <th style="width: 15em;" class="right"><strong>ALP</strong></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>SUB TOTAL G-0</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>0</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>0</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>G-1</td>
      <td>A6011</td>
      <td>00923917</td>
      <td>FRANSISKA YULIANA B.D.</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>00905445</td>
      <td>NESTI RAHAYU</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-1</td>
      <td>A6011</td>
      <td>00923917</td>
      <td>FRANSISKA YULIANA B.D.</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>00905448</td>
      <td>AISYAH</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">30.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-1</td>
      <td>A6011</td>
      <td>00923917</td>
      <td>FRANSISKA YULIANA B.D.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>00905454</td>
      <td>ADYANTA YOGA PRADANA</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-1</td>
      <td>A7924</td>
      <td>00947903</td>
      <td>MELVA SUPARDI</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>00947903</td>
      <td>MELVA SUPARDI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>SUB TOTAL G-1</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>5</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>48.000.000</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>G-2</td>
      <td>A5974</td>
      <td>00923389</td>
      <td>ALI WIDODO</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>00918088</td>
      <td>JOHN HENDRI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">12.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-2</td>
      <td>A5993</td>
      <td>00923678</td>
      <td>PATENSAROHA PANJAITAN</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>00924255</td>
      <td>PURNAMA MARINTAN</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">4</td>
      <td class="right">28.800.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-2</td>
      <td>A8603</td>
      <td>00966488</td>
      <td>RISANG RUDI PERMADI</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>00966488</td>
      <td>RISANG RUDI PERMADI</td>
      <td>SM</td>
      <td>SMG043</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">31.200.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>SUB TOTAL G-2</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>8</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>72.000.000</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A2190</td>
      <td>00906041</td>
      <td>LIESTYANINGSIH PRASETYO</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>00906041</td>
      <td>LIESTYANINGSIH PRASETYO</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A6659</td>
      <td>00910973</td>
      <td>FERMOLINA</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>00910973</td>
      <td>FERMOLINA</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">4</td>
      <td class="right">73.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A5974</td>
      <td>00923389</td>
      <td>ALI WIDODO</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>00911258</td>
      <td>CAROTRIANA HARTIANI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">8.400.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A7824</td>
      <td>00913029</td>
      <td>YULI PURWANTI</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>00913029</td>
      <td>YULI PURWANTI</td>
      <td>SM</td>
      <td>SMG043</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">4.800.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A8603</td>
      <td>00966488</td>
      <td>RISANG RUDI PERMADI</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>00925635</td>
      <td>RICHA DEWI AZDANI</td>
      <td>SM</td>
      <td>SMG043</td>
      <td class="right">4</td>
      <td class="right">18.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A2006</td>
      <td>00905496</td>
      <td>MARYANAH</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>00941248</td>
      <td>ROCHIMI DIAN PUSPITASARI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">9.600.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A7240</td>
      <td>00942942</td>
      <td>SOE ESTI MURNIATI</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>00942942</td>
      <td>SOE ESTI MURNIATI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">3</td>
      <td class="right">23.040.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A8053</td>
      <td>00951213</td>
      <td>A. M. GANDA MARPAUNG</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>00951213</td>
      <td>A. M. GANDA MARPAUNG</td>
      <td>JB3</td>
      <td>JAM707</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">4.800.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A2006</td>
      <td>00905496</td>
      <td>MARYANAH</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>00953857</td>
      <td>MOCH KEMAL ASYAF</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">36.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-3</td>
      <td>A2006</td>
      <td>00905496</td>
      <td>MARYANAH</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>00968671</td>
      <td>GITA NELWAN</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">12.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>SUB TOTAL G-3</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>21</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>195.640.000</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A4040</td>
      <td>00909748</td>
      <td>KARINA</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>00909748</td>
      <td>KARINA</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">54.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A6091</td>
      <td>00910151</td>
      <td>NONAH SUHANAH</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>00910517</td>
      <td>ALFIAN IDRUS</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A5974</td>
      <td>00923389</td>
      <td>ALI WIDODO</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>00912869</td>
      <td>ROHMAT</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">12.060.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A6659</td>
      <td>00910973</td>
      <td>FERMOLINA</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>00925358</td>
      <td>ANDRIYANI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">8.400.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A6789</td>
      <td>00909167</td>
      <td>WAHYU RIDWAN NUGROHO</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>00938577</td>
      <td>ACHMAD TAUFIK</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">4.800.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A8822</td>
      <td>00944260</td>
      <td>DESSY RANTAU WIDIASARI</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>00944260</td>
      <td>DESSY RANTAU WIDIASARI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A8896</td>
      <td>00946599</td>
      <td>ILHAM WAHYUDIN</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>00946599</td>
      <td>ILHAM WAHYUDIN</td>
      <td>SB</td>
      <td>SKB008</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A6091</td>
      <td>00910151</td>
      <td>NONAH SUHANAH</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>00947779</td>
      <td>YENNI CHRISTINA</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">12.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A7204</td>
      <td>00941979</td>
      <td>MANUELA R SIAGIAN</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>00959611</td>
      <td>LAURENTIA DYAH IKA G</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">10.400.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A2042</td>
      <td>00905588</td>
      <td>HENY BAYU SAFITRI</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>00965234</td>
      <td>YASAN</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">12.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-4</td>
      <td>A6659</td>
      <td>00910973</td>
      <td>FERMOLINA</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>00968489</td>
      <td>ANDRE PERBAWA</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">3</td>
      <td class="right">36.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>SUB TOTAL G-4</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>14</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>167.660.000</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A2157</td>
      <td>00905917</td>
      <td>SYARIFAH</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>00905917</td>
      <td>SYARIFAH</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">4</td>
      <td class="right">30.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A2043</td>
      <td>00905590</td>
      <td>BUNGAIDAL ADKHIA</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>00911669</td>
      <td>ZULFIKAR</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">18.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A8896</td>
      <td>00946599</td>
      <td>ILHAM WAHYUDIN</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>00914524</td>
      <td>RITAWATI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">3</td>
      <td class="right">13.200.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A8896</td>
      <td>00946599</td>
      <td>ILHAM WAHYUDIN</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>00923652</td>
      <td>DEDEN AMARULLAH</td>
      <td>SB</td>
      <td>SKB008</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">4.200.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A6916</td>
      <td>00937689</td>
      <td>SUDIRMAN</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>00937689</td>
      <td>SUDIRMAN</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A8199</td>
      <td>00944267</td>
      <td>DEWI KARTINI</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>00944267</td>
      <td>DEWI KARTINI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">30.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A8131</td>
      <td>00954706</td>
      <td>HENDRA SURYA</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>00954706</td>
      <td>HENDRA SURYA</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">15.600.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A6307</td>
      <td>00911807</td>
      <td>BERTA M PURBA</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>00964680</td>
      <td>DANIEL</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">6.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A8822</td>
      <td>00944260</td>
      <td>DESSY RANTAU WIDIASARI</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>00967703</td>
      <td>YANTI ARIANI</td>
      <td>TN1</td>
      <td>JKT0A1</td>
      <td class="right">2</td>
      <td class="right">18.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G-5</td>
      <td>A7824</td>
      <td>00913029</td>
      <td>YULI PURWANTI</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>00968122</td>
      <td>NOVIA BETSY CLARISSA</td>
      <td>SM</td>
      <td>SMG043</td>
      <td class="right">1</td>
      <td class="right">24.000.000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>SUB TOTAL G-5</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>18</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>165.000.000</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>

    <tr bgcolor="#ededf9">
      <td colspan="8" class="right"><strong>GRAND TOTAL</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>66</strong></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>648.300.000</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</div><!-- #orig_table -->
<h2>Final Table:</h2>
<div class="finalTable"></div>
```